# If $H$ is a subgroup of order $p$, then show that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group with $|G| = pn$ with $p > n, p$ is a prime numbers and $H$ is a subgroup of order $p$, then show that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove that $H$ is a unique subgroup of $G$ of order $p$. Suppose that there exists one more subgroup $H'\leq G$ of order $p$. Then $H\cap H'=\{1\}$, hence $|HH'|=|H||H'|/|H\cap H'|=p^2$, сonsequently $|G|\geq p^2>pn$ - contradiction.

Comment: Can you please give hint to show $H\cap H’=\{1\}$?

Comment: I got it. Let $H’$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $p$ and $H\neq H’$. Assume towards contradiction $H\cap H’\neq\{1\}$. Then $\exists 1\neq h\in H\cap H’$. So $\langle h\rangle \subseteq H,H’$. By Lagrange theorem, $|\langle h\rangle |$ divides $p=|H|=|H’|$. That means $|\langle h\rangle |=1$ or $p$. Since $h\neq e$, $|\langle h\rangle |=p$. Thus $\langle h\rangle =H=H’$. We reach contradiction. Hence $H\cap H’=\{1\}$. Let $g\in G$. Since $H\cong gHg^{-1}$, we have $|H|=| gHg^{-1}|=p$. Since $\exists !$ subgroup with order $p$, we have $H=gHg^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$. So $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

By Sylow's theorems, the number $m$ of subgroups of order $p$ is congruent
to $1$ modulo $p$. Also $m$ divides $|G|=pn$. What can $m$ be?

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_p$ denote the number of Sylow $p$ subgroups of $G$.

Then Sylow's theorems tell us that $m_p \equiv 1 \mod p$ and that $m_p|np$ and combining these two facts yields $m_p|n.$

Now since $m_p|n$ and also $m_p \equiv 1 \mod p$ we must have $m_p=1$ (since $n<p$).

So we have exactly one Sylow subgroup of size $p$ so this must be $H$.

Finally we have that Sylow subgroups are conjugate in $G$ so combining this with the fact that there is only one Sylow $p$ subgroup, $H$ we must have $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g \in G$ that is $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$.