# Exercise 14, Section 2.4 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups

**Corollary 4.9.** If $H$ is a subgroup of index $n$ in a group $G$ and no non trivial normal subgroup of $G$ is contained in $H$, then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

**Corollary 4.10.** If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$ of index $p$, where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of $G$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.

---

> If $|G|=pn$, with $p\gt n$, $p$ prime, and $H$ is a subgroup of order $p$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.

**My attempt:** By Lagrange theorem, $$\begin{align}|G| &= |H|[G:H]\\ &= p[G:H]\\ &=pn \\ \end{align}.$$ So $[G:H]=n$. If $n$ is prime, then $H\lhd G$ (by corollary 4.10). If $n$ is not prime. We claim $\exists \langle e\rangle \neq K\lhd G$ such that $K\subseteq H$. Assume towards contradiction, $\nexists$ such $K$. By corollary 4.9, $G\cong$ subgroup of $S_n$. By Lagrange theorem, $|G|=|\text{subgroup of }S_n|$ divides $|S_n|=n!$. That is $np\mid n!$. Which implies $p\mid (n-1)!$ and $p=i$ for some $1\leq i\leq n-1$. But $p\gt n$. Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $\exists \langle e\rangle \neq K\lhd G$ such that $K\subseteq H$. By Lagrange theorem, $|K|$ divides $|H|=p$. So $|K|=1$ or $p$. Since $K\neq \langle e\rangle$, we have $|K|=p$. Thus $K=H$ is normal in $G$. **Is my proof correct?**

I am uncertain about following step in my proof: Which implies $p\mid (n-1)!$ and $p=i$ for some $1\leq i\leq n-1$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2253487/861687) is an alternative approach to above exercise which doesn’t use Sylow's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. If $\frac{n!}{np}\in\mathbb{Z}$, then, of course, $\frac{(n-1)!}{p}\in\mathbb{Z}.$ If a prime $p$ divides a $(n-1)!$, it means, by definition of prime number, that it divides a number $i\in\{2,\dots, n-1\}$. So, there is at least a multiple of $p$ in $\{2,\dots, n-1\},$ and this means that $p\in\{2,\dots,n-1\}.$

Comment: Thank you so much for the verification. I was unsure about that part of the proof (mainly because first draft of my proof was wildly different from my present draft).